# How to stop zoom level of content in webview using windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How to stop zooming level of content in webview using windows phone 8.1

```
webFreeFlow.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

I am using that approach but this doesn't work to plz give me any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this through [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) and setting the `user-scalable` to `no` in JavaScript so that it produces something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Some additional resources [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport/)